# Double divide by zero: Why is the result inconsistent?

Tags: java, floating-point, double

Why are the results of:

```
double a = 0.0/0.0;
double b = 0/0.0;
```

= **NaN**

But the results of for example:

```
double e = 0.1/0.0;
double e = 12.0/0.0;
double f = 1.0/0.0;
```

= **Infinity**

I understand that `double` or `float` divisions are somehow a little bit different. I am pretty happy with the resulting **NaN** because the result is not defined when something is divided by zero. But why they defined that the result of something greater than zero divided by zero is **Infitity**? Has this something todo with the method they use to perform the division of floating points?

Comment: This is behaving exactly as per JLS 15.17.2: "Division of a zero by a zero results in NaN... Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity." What would you propose the results be? This is pretty common - possibly as required by IEEE754 even.

Comment: all this math expressions 0/0, ∞/∞, 0 × ∞, ∞ − ∞,  1∞ and ∞0. produce an Indeterminate form

Comment: @JonSkeet I excpected the result to be the same (both NaN) and not dependant on the numerator of the division.

Comment: @ClaudioP: Then basically your expectations were inappropriate, given that it's well-specified what it will do. You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682005 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other answers that specify that this is in the standard and therefore "expected" behavior.  You seem to want to know why the standard is like that.  I would guess that the reason is that some expressions have well-defined limits (as in calculus) and some do not even have a limit.  The ones with a well-defined limit get a signed infinity (since that is the limit).  The ones like 0/0 get NaN because there is no limit there. (The limit from the left is negative infinity and the limit from the right is positive infinity.)  In all cases, when I say "limit", I mean `limit of n/x as x -> 0`, where `n` is the fixed numerator.

Comment: Thank you for the possible reason of the standard definition.

Answer (score 3):

JLS [15.17.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) clearly states that

> Division of a zero by a zero results in **NaN**; division of zero by any other finite value results in a signed zero. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.
>
> Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed **infinity**. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.

The JLS also says about the difference between these constants in operations.

> If either operand is **NaN**, the result is **NaN**.
>
> Division of an **infinity** by an **infinity** results in **NaN**.
>
> Division of an **infinity** by a finite value results in a signed **infinity**. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.

Not inconsistent at all.

Comment: Explaining the bit representations of NaN and Infinity is not helpful.  The asker seems to be clear on the *concepts* of NaN and Infinity, just not the reasoning for the outcomes.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I would be happy if someone could state me the reason for this definition. Why they don't use NaN for both?

Answer (score 2):

According to math definition following operations result in an **undetermined result** and that is what ***NAN*** represent!
Following undetermined result can be:

- 0/0,
- ∞/∞,
- 0*∞,
- ∞-∞,
- 0^0,
- 1^∞,
- 0^∞

java match almost all of them (except ∞^0 and 0^0)

```
    // 0/0
    double a = 0.0 / 0.0;
    System.out.println(a);
    // ∞/∞
    a = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY / Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    System.out.println(a);
    // 0*∞
    a = 0 * Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    System.out.println(a);
    // ∞-∞
    a = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY - Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    System.out.println(a);
    // 0^0
    a = Math.pow(0, 0);
    System.out.println(a);
    // 1^∞
    a = Math.pow(1, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    System.out.println(a);
    // ∞^0
    a = Math.pow(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0);
    System.out.println(a);
```