# How computer computes Negative(-) and Positive(+) Infinity?

Tags: math, operating-system, computer-science, infinity

We all know, if we divide (1.0/0.0) we will get +Infinity and if we divide (-1.0/0.0) we will get -Infinity! I want to know How computers calculate this value, internally ??

PS: I wondering why I didn't find any question regarding this in any of StackExchange community!

Comment: Related question, with answer, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682005/why-does-division-by-zero-in-ieee754-standard-results-in-infinite-value

Comment: In IEEE 754, the results of the division you show will depend on the sign of the zero !

Comment: @YvesDaoust This is an important detail to point out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It will detect that you divide by 0 and not do the actual division.

Long answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311155/will-a-computer-attempt-to-divide-by-zero