# Why does dividing by zero for Float not raise an exception in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Dividing by zero for `Integer` raises a `ZeroDivisionError`:

```
0 / 0 # ZeroDivisionError
```

However dividing by zero for `Float` does not:

```
0.0 / 0   #NaN
0 / 0.0   #NaN
0.0 /0.0  #NaN    
1.0 / 0   #Infinity
1 / 0.0   #Infinity
1.0 /0.0  #Infinity
```

I was wondering why is there this difference in behaviour for `Integer` and `Float` in Ruby?

Comment: It's not Ruby-specific. It is the behavior defined in IEEE 754. Here is a good answer that provides some rationale: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14684474/8008340

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with almost all programming languages, ruby's implementation of floating-point arithmetic is compliant to the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Exception_handling) standard.

This specification (linked above) defines five exceptions that **must** (at least by default) be handled in a specific way:

> - **Invalid operation: mathematically undefined, e.g., the square root of a negative number. By default, returns qNaN.**
> - **Division by zero: an operation on finite operands gives an exact infinite result, e.g., 1/0 or log(0). By default, returns ±infinity.**
> - Overflow: a result is too large to be represented correctly (i.e., its exponent with an unbounded exponent range would be larger than emax). By default, returns ±infinity for the round-to-nearest modes (and follows the rounding rules for the directed rounding modes).
> - Underflow: a result is very small (outside the normal range) and is inexact. By default, returns a subnormal or zero (following the rounding rules).
> - Inexact: the exact (i.e., unrounded) result is not representable exactly. By default, returns the correctly rounded result.

Therefore `1.0/0` must equal `+Infinity`, and `0.0/0` must equal `NaN`.

---

`Integer` objects do not conform to the above standard. (There is no `Infinity` or `NaN`, and all operations are exact.) Therefore, it was a language-specific decision to raise an exception for operations such as `1/0`.

Comment: Incidentally, you may also encounter some other "odd" behaviour in floating-point numbers, such as `Float::NAN == Float::NAN #=> false`. Once again, this is compliant with the IEEE 754 specification.

Comment: The statement that these exceptions “must” be handled in a specific way may confuse readers. These results are the required results under default exception handling. Implementations may provide for alternate exception handling, which may, among other things, substitute any user-specified result. Also, this answer glosses over some of the details that trigger exceptions.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that a “floating-point exception” is a case where the mathematical result is exceptional. It is not a C++ or Ruby type of exception that causes a change of program control (although a change of control may occur with alternate exception handling).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've edited my answer to say *(at least by default)* to be more accurate, thank you. And yes, I did gloss over some details around what constitutes an "exception" - but the original question only discussed `1/0` and `0/0`, which are quite straightforward scenarios.