# I'm getting a Divide by zero error on Status Bar portion of script

Tags: csv, divide-by-zero

I've been using this script with no issues and all of the sudden, i'm getting a divide by zero error. the script is to update or change a couple of attributes and a colleague added the counter/status since we sometimes have hundreds of changes to make.
I've been using powershell ise since going to Win11 as I was having issues with regular PS.

I tried pulling the data from a fresh csv file thinking that may have been the issue; no luck.
Here is what I have:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -force

    import-module Activedirectory
    $Path = "C:\Users\cn116943\Input\ad_data_TN_IP_update.csv"
    $CSV = import-csv $Path
    $CRED = get-credential "Centene\a_cn116943"

    #Counter for progress status
    $counter = 0
    $total = $CSV.count

    foreach($row in $csv){

        $counter++
        Write-Progress -Activity "Processing: $row" -Status "$($counter) of $($total)" -        PercentComplete (($counter/$total)*100)

    if($row.action -eq 'update'){
        set-aduser $row.user -credential $cred -replace @{ipPhone= "$($row.phone)"}
        set-aduser $row.user -credential $cred -replace @{telephonenumber= "$($row.phone)"} 
    }

    if($row.action -eq 'remove'){
        set-aduser $row.user -credential $cred -Clear ipPhone
        set-aduser $row.user -credential $cred -Clear telephonenumber
```

Comment: As a quick-fix, change `PercentComplete (($counter/$total)*100)` to `PercentComplete (($counter/($total+1))*100)` (though it's curious how `$total` is zero when it has to enter the `foreach`  which can't happen when it is empty...

Comment: Dai, that was perfect.  My counter/status bar is now working.  thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comment as an answer:

...in this line ([multi-line syntax used for clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command)):

```
Write-Progress `
    -Activity "Processing: $row" `
    -Status "$($counter) of $($total)" `
    -PercentComplete (($counter/$total)*100)
```

...the `-PercentComplete` parameter argument expression is:

```
( $counter / $total )*100
```

...so when `$total` is `0` this will cause a divide-by-zero error (the `-PercentComplete` parameter is typed as `Int32` instead of a floating-point type, so a divide-by-zero is a fatal error instead of resulting in `Infinity` (at least [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682005/why-does-division-by-zero-in-ieee754-standard-results-in-infinite-value)). An odd design choice by Microsoft there.

As a *quick-fix* (i.e. a hack), one can prevent divide-by-zero by simply adding `+1` to `$total`:

```
Write-Progress `
    -Activity "Processing: $row" `
    -Status "$($counter) of $($total)" `
    -PercentComplete (($counter/($total+1))*100)
```

...though it's curiuous that it's running the `Write-Progress` command given the `foreach($row in $csv) {` loop shouldn't be entered when `$CSV.count` (i.e. `$total`) is `0`). I assume you had the same `$counter/$total` expression elsewhere in your script.